# Nearley grammar matches the same bit of text as a terminal and a non-terminal one after the other, producing wrong result

Tags: parsing, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree, symbolic-math, nearley

Grammar noob here.

I need to parse math formulas similar to those accepted by SymPy and transform them into some kind of left-to-right syntax tree, using Nearley [this grammar](https://gist.github.com/Morpheu5/915feecf45dba50280570a60831a517f).

The problem appears when I have an expression like `a*sin(x)*y` where `sin` is first recognised as a `SY`, and then as a `FN`. I think this is sort of a necessary evil if I want to be able to parse variables (that's what `SY` is for). The result is something like

```
[ { type: 'Symbol',
    properties: { letter: 'a' },
    children:
     { right:
        { type: 'Symbol',
          properties: { letter: 'sin' },
          children:
           { right:
              { type: 'Fn',
                properties: { name: 'sin' },
                children:
                 { argument: { type: 'Symbol', properties: { letter: 'x' }, children: {} },
                   right: { type: 'Symbol', properties: { letter: 'y' }, children: {} } } } } } },
    position: { x: 200, y: 200 } } ]
```

Even worse, when the expression is `a*sin(x)^y`, I get

```
[ { type: 'Symbol',
    properties: { letter: 'a' },
    children:
     { right:
        { type: 'Symbol',
          properties: { letter: 'sin' },
          children:
           { right:
              { type: 'Fn',
                properties: { name: 'sin' },
                children:
                 { argument: { type: 'Symbol', properties: { letter: 'x' }, children: {} },
                   superscript: { type: 'Symbol', properties: { letter: 'y' }, children: {} },
                   right: [Circular] } } } } },
    position: { x: 200, y: 200 } } ]
```

I presume `[Circular]` means there's some sort of wicked loop somewhere.

I suspect I could resolve the first issue above hardcoding a check that replaces the `SY` with the correct `FN` if the two "match", but I'd rather avoid such a botch-up. I have no clue as to what's happening with the second one -- though I have been on this for a full day and my mind is likely clouded. I'll investigate more once I get to the office today.

Any clues?

---

**EDIT**: I managed to "solve" the first issue (`Fn` as a child of a `Symbol` of the same name) with a horrible hack. The circular problem remains. I'm investigating, but I am probably going to find another horrible hack. I'd rather see a fix for the grammar rather than for the transformation functions, if at all possible.

Comment: The way to handle keywords is explained in the [Moo docs](https://github.com/no-context/moo/blob/master/README.md#keywords). Don't try to do it with your parser. It's possible but it complicates things, as you have seen.

Comment: In fact I am handling "keywords" (function names) with moo, but "variables" can have any name, from a simple `x` to a more complicated `alpha_t0`, so I can't handle those with moo.

Comment: 'but "variables" can have any name, from a simple x to a more complicated alpha_t0, so I can't handle those with moo' That's just not true. You can (and should) handle arbitrary identifiers in the lexer and rici's link tells you exactly how to (though I personally find the fact that moo doesn't properly support maximal much offensive).

Comment: Ha, I had overlooked that. I now have a `Id: { match: /[a-zA-Z]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/, keywords: {` with all the function names as `keywords`, which seems to work, though I have since scaled back to a simpler transformation, so I have yet to test with with my complicated linked structure. The problem I'm facing right now though is that `alpha` and `alpha_t` are parsed correctly, but `alpha_t0` generates an ambiguous parsing: https://pastebin.com/qAngK1zU

Comment: Ah, that's because the digit is independently parsed as a number. Sigh.